# how to load image using image path in gridview in android studio?

Tags: android, gridview, android-asynctask

how do i display image using the imagepath fetched from mysql database into gridview. i tried lot but unable to do.

this is my asynctask code:

```
public class sampling_info extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SamplingActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String doc = dcname.toString();
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> namevaluepair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("docname", doc));


        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_SAMPLING, "POST",
                namevaluepair);


        return json;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();

        if (json != null) {
            try {

                JSONArray jarray = json.getJSONArray("product_entered");

                Log.d("jarray in sampling : ", "" + jarray.toString());

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jobj = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String docname = jobj.getString("docname");
                    String imagep= jobj.getString("image_path");

                    GridItem gItem= new  GridItem();

                    gItem.setTitle("sagar");
                     gItem.setImage(imagep);

                     mgrid.add(gItem);

                    Log.d("jobj : ", "" + jobj);
                    Log.d("jobj docname", "" + docname);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(SamplingActivity.this, R.layout.grid_item_layout,mgrid);
            gridview.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        }

    }
```

i this asynctask am fetching imagepath from database and storing it in **imagep** variable and passing it to **GridItem class**

This is my griditem class :

```
public class GridItem {
private Bitmap image;
private String title,image1;

public GridItem(Bitmap image) {
    this.image=image;
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}

public Bitmap setImage(String image) {  // this is where am trying to set my image but can't do.
    try {


    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is my adapter class :

```
public GridViewAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId,
                       ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData) {
    super(mContext, layoutResourceId, mGridData);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mGridData = mGridData;
}

/**
 * Updates grid data and refresh grid items.
 *
 * @param mGridData
 */
public void setGridData(ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData) {
    this.mGridData = mGridData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    //ViewHolder holder;
ImageView   imageView = (ImageView) row
            .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        //  holder = new ViewHolder();
        //imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_title);


   imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    } else {

    }

    GridItem item = mGridData.get(position);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());



    return row;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

First of all, include last version of jar file from 'lib' directory to your project

in Adapter :

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = null;
DisplayImageOptions options;
```

in Adapter's Contractor :

```
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            /*.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer((int) 27.5f))*/
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.thumb_square)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.thumb_square)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.thumb_square)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            /*.postProcessor(new BitmapProcessor() {
                @Override
                public Bitmap process(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
                    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
                    float r = ((float)h / (float)w);
                    ExceptionHelpers.dLog("POST_PROCESSOR", "width : " + w + " , height : " + h + " , R1 : " + r + " , W : " + UIHelpers.width + " , Percent W : " + UIHelpers.setPercentW(r));
                    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, UIHelpers.width, UIHelpers.setPercentW(r), false);
                }
            })*/
            .build();
```

and getView :

```
String imgURL = "http://www.website.com/images/image_path.png";
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext));
imageLoader.displayImage(imgURL, holder.img_view, options);
```

Comment: will this image loader work for grid view and how to initialize image path variable

Comment: Yes it works on ListView, GridView, RecyclerView. i used it and i sure

Comment: : i'll try it and respond to you very soon.

Comment: i have used Universal Image Loader. but getting null pointer exception. can u please check this post. i have posted separate question regarding this here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285001/how-to-convert-jsonarray-to-string-array-in-android

Comment: Thanks @AndroSco. it worked. some little changes i made. but worked.

Comment: your welcome, also `displayer` used to radius, set it add 300f (big number) to have cyrcle image in dislay

Answer (score 0):

First of all dont store the bitmap in modelClass, Alternatively you can add sd card path or live url of an image(`http://...`)

Loading the image:
-- I suggest you to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library
Code sample:

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(url) // pass your image url
        .centerCrop()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
        .crossFade() //animate the image
        .into(myImageView);
```